# Use of Can vs. May

Tags: word-choice

Should I use *can* or *may* in the following sentence: "For more information on how you *can* help with wreath sponsorship..." ?

Comment: You can use either. You may use either. Which you use depends on what you want to say. Do you want to stress *ability* or *permission*?

Comment: I would use *can* here, because I am referring to their ability to help us, not how we deign to allow them to help us. :)

Answer (score 1):

One of my old instructors used to tease us about this. A student would ask:

> "Can I go to the bathroom?"

To which he would respond:

> "I don't know, can you?"

So while you certainly *may* use "can" in that context, the term concerns *ability* (or *capacity*) more than it does *permission*.

> "May I go to the bathroom?"

Would be deemed the technically "proper" form of the question.

But again, as others in the comments note, it's not a significant difference. Both are used interchangeably in modern speech.

Comment: In your example, what follows may explain how you are both able and permitted to help. So either word is grammatically correct, but they differ somewhat in meaning. In your original example, I suspect that what is important is to explain the various ways that a person is able to help, and so I would prefer "can.. In the example given by Aleksandr, the capacity to go to the bathroom would seldom be in question, but, if the question pertains to permission to go, that deserves "may." Modern American speech often ignores these useful distinctions, but they are usually observed In careful writing.

Comment: @JeffMorrow make this an answer...